# What is the German equivalent of "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."?

Tags: translation

What is the German equivalent of "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."?

That is: A phrase used for font selection that contains all the letters of the alphabet.

Comment: Wasn't that a sentence to check the function of mechanic teletypes which had no uppercase characters?

Comment: See also [German Pangrams](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5015/german-pangrams/5016#5016)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> Franz jagt im komplett verwahrlosten Taxi quer durch Bayern.

It roughly translates to:

> Franz is racing 
>   through Bayern 
>   in a totally shabby
>   taxicab.

Comment: Is this phrase actually used for font selection?

Comment: @thei: As far as I know, yes.

Comment: That phrase doesn't have a ß which you would probably want if using it to assess a font.

Comment: @Twelve47: It also lacks `ö ä ü` if you mean that. But it is used most of the time, for better/more complete examples [see sl0815 answer](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/103/what-is-the-german-equivalent-of-the-quick-brown-fox-jumps-over-the-lazy-dog/106#106).

Comment: It does, I was just curious is there was a phrase containing these characters that is regularly used in German speaking countries when looking at a font selection.

Comment: @Twelve47: Also see my answer.

Comment: @Twelve47, true but racing shabby taxicabs and chasing boxers are so much cooler than lazy dogs or quick foxes :)

Comment: @thei: Yes; that's the sentence used for the font previewer in German versions of Windows.

Answer (score 42):

Sätze, die alle Buchstaben des Alphabets enthalten, heißen **Pangramme** (von griechisch πᾶν γράμμα: "jeder Buchstabe").

Es gibt im Deutschen eine Reihe davon. Hier einige Beispiele ([Wikipedia hat eine ausführliche Aufzählung](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangramm#Liste_deutscher_Pangramme)):

Pangramme ohne äöü und ß:

- Vogel Quax zwickt Johnys Pferd Bim.
- Sylvia wagt quick den Jux bei Pforzheim.
- Prall vom Whisky flog Quax den Jet zu Bruch.
- Franz jagt im komplett verwahrlosten Taxi quer durch Bayern.
- Stanleys Expeditionszug quer durch Afrika wird von jedermann bewundert.

Pangramme mit äöü und ß:

- Falsches Üben von Xylophonmusik quält jeden größeren Zwerg.
- Zwölf Boxkämpfer jagen Viktor quer über den großen Sylter Deich.
- Polyfon zwitschernd aßen Mäxchens Vögel Rüben, Joghurt und Quark.
- Schweißgequält zündet Typograf Jakob verflixt öde Pangramme an.
- Vom Ödipuskomplex maßlos gequält, übt Wilfried zyklisches Jodeln.

Comment: Ich wusste gar nicht, das zyklisches Jodeln bei akutem Ödipuskomplex hilft. Gibt's da Studien?

Comment: @balpha Medizinisches zyklisches Jodeln ist derzeit nur in Bayern versuchsweise erlaubt. Österreich und Südtirol haben auch Interesse an der Therapie gezeigt.

Comment: +1 für die Xylophonmusik :-)

Comment: Ich habe eine Frage... gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen "im Deutschen" und "in Deutsch"? Kann man beides abwechselnd verwenden?

Comment: "_Auf_ Deutsch", bitte.

Comment: @TomHundt https://german.stackexchange.com/a/1750/44

Answer (score 13):

I like

> Zwölf Boxkämpfer jagen Viktor quer über den großen Sylter Deich

but see for yourself at [Pangramm](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangramm)

EDIT: rough translation: twelve boxers are chasing Victor across the big levee of Sylt.

Answer (score 11):

Another one with the nice property of containing each character including the ß and the umlauts exactly once:

> „Fix, Schwyz!“, quäkt Jürgen blöd vom Paß.

Please note, that the spelling is not quite correct in this sentence. In modern German spelling, one would write Pass instead of Paß.

Answer (score 5):

A German pangram is

> Kaufen Sie jede Woche vier gute, bequeme Pelze! xy

In English:

> Buy four good, comfortable fur coats every week. xy

The "xy" at the end of the sentence are there to complete the alphabet. This pangram was used to test telegram lines (where umlauts and ß weren't used).

Comment: Hätte ich das nicht gerade [auf Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangramm) gelesen, so hätte ich mich doch sehr gewundert, was das "xy" soll - ein Satz ist das nicht. (Übrigens, den Pelzen fehlt das "e".)

Comment: Maybe better to add the English translation.