# Wann kann man "in Deutsch" und wann "auf Deutsch" verwenden?

Tags: preposition

Ich kenne die beiden Ausdrücke **"auf Deutsch"** und **"in Deutsch"** (oder *"auf Englisch"* und *"in Englisch"*). Sind die beiden Präpositionen in diesen Formen immer miteinander austauschbar?

Kann das jemand anhand einiger Beispiele klären?

Comment: Ich würde sagen, dass "in Deutsch" einfach nur falsch ist, aber sicher bin ich mir nicht.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Es scheint, dass man heutzutage beide Varianten verwenden kann. Ich habe eine Aussage gefunden, dass der Duden "auf Deutsch" als gehobener bezeichnet, kann dort jedoch den Beleg nicht finden. Ich sage in der Regel auch eher "auf Deutsch". "In Deutsch" wird häufig als Anglizismus beschrieben, als zu wörtlich übersetzte Version von "in German". Möglicherweise rührt daher auch die potenzielle Ablehnung - ebenso wie etwas nicht in 2011, wohl aber 2011 oder im Jahr 2011 passieren kann. In [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denglisch) findet sich eine entsprechende Aussage als Beispiel zu Grammatik-Anglizismen, die jedoch nicht belegt wird:

> in English/German – in Englisch, in Deutsch (statt „auf Englisch“, „auf Deutsch“ oder „im Englischen“, „im Deutschen“)

Hier sollte man keiner Verwechslung unterliegen. Selbstverständlich stand schon immer "in" in folgendem Satz:

> Er ist flüssig in Deutsch wie Englisch. (Aber: er kann sich flüssig *auf* Deutsch wie Englisch ausdrücken.)

Ebenso natürlich, wenn es sich um das Schulfach handelt:

> Er muss eine Arbeit in Deutsch schreiben.

Ebenfalls fand sich eine Aussage, dass "Deutsch" in "in Deutsch" ein Substantiv ist, das die Sprache bezeichnet, während es in "auf Deutsch" ein substantiviertes Adjektiv darstellt. Im Duden finden sich jedoch bei beiden Einträgen (Adjektiv und Substantiv) auch beide Beispiele - das spricht entweder gegen diese These oder dafür, dass die Variante mit "in" bereits in der Sprache angekommen ist (ähnlich wie "Sinn machen").

---

Rein intuitiv würde ich beide Formen für austauschbar halten, wenn jemand etwas deutschsprachig formuliert:

> Er hält seine Rede auf Deutsch. Er verfasst den Brief in Deutsch.

Ähnliche Beispiele finden sich im Duden. Die erste Variante klingt für mich deutlich besser. Geht es jedoch nicht direkt um das Verfassen, scheint mir "in" nicht so verkehrt zu klingen:

> Hier finden Sie Beispiele in Deutsch und Englisch.

Vielleicht weil sich hier die Verlängerung "in deutscher und englischer Sprache" noch mehr aufdrängt als im obigen Beispiel. Aber eigentlich ist in dieser Form "auf" auch nicht verkehrt.

Möchte man dem Deutschen hier noch eine Qualität mitgeben, ist "in" erforderlich:

> Hier finden Sie Beispiele in *gutem* Deutsch.

Das ist interessant, weil eine andere Variante das "auf" erfordert:

> Das kann man auf *gut* Deutsch so sagen.

Fragt jemand nach einer Übersetzung, würde ich immer "auf" bevorzugen:

> Was heißt das auf Deutsch?

Hier wäre natürlich die Variante mit Artikel auch gut:

> Wie sagt man das im Deutschen?

Deutschlernende sollten dabei darauf achten, dass sich das "in" nicht auf eine Richtung bezieht. Selbstverständlich kann man nur *ins Deutsche*, nicht jedoch *auf das Deutsche* übersetzen.

(Hinweis: ich widerstand der Versuchung, jedes einzelne "Deutsch" durch eine andere Sprache zu ersetzen, um den Text interessanter zu gestalten - selbstverständlich könnte man jede andere Sprache substituieren.)

Comment: +1 für die sehr gute, ausführliche Antwort.

Comment: +1 exzellente Antwort!

Comment: *Er ist flüssig in Deutsch wie Englisch.* Dieser Satz ist so - wie du schon sagst - ein Anglizismus und auf Deutsch eigentlich nicht richitg. Selbiges gilt für die anderen Beispiele: Die Formulierung *in Deutsch* ist nicht korrekt, allenfalls wird sie umgangssprachlich verwendet. Korrekte Formulierungen sind *auf Deutsch*, *im Deutschen* und *in deutscher Sprache*. Auch in Verbindung mit Adjektiven heißt es - wie richtig geschrieben - *in gutem Deutsch* etc.

Answer (score 24):

"auf Deutsch": von ["deutsch"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/deutsch) (Adjektiv)
bezieht sich laut Duden auf die "Sprache der Bevölkerung besonders Deutschlands, Österreichs und in Teilen der Schweiz".

> Sag's auf Deutsch.

"in Deutsch": von ["das Deutsch"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Deutsch) (Substantiv)
bezieht sich auf die deutsche Sprache eines Einzelnen oder einer Gruppe, oder auf das Unterrichtsfach.

> Er schrieb mir einen Brief in gutem Deutsch.
>
> Ich habe eine Vier in Deutsch.

"im Deutschen": von ["das Deutsche"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Deutsche_Sprache_Deutsch) (substantiviertes Adjektiv)
bezieht sich auf die deutsche Sprache im Allgemeinen.

> Der Konjunktiv wird im Deutschen in
> der indirekten Rede verwendet.

Comment: Das ist interessant, ich bin ebenso auf den Unterschied zwischen Adjektiv und Substantiv gestoßen. Allerdings finden sich im Duden bei beiden Einträgen Beispielsätze mit "in" und "auf", die sich auf die Sprache beziehen (und nicht auf das Unterrichtsfach). Insofern sagt mir dein zweites Beispiel nicht zu, weil es die Variante "bezieht sich auf die deutsche Sprache eines Einzelnen oder einer Gruppe" nicht hervorhebt, die hier problematischer zu sein scheint. Dein erstes Beispiel zeigt übrigens *ebenso wie das letzte* das substantivierte Adjektiv, hier gibt es zwei Varianten.

Comment: Trotzdem +1 für die knappe Erklärung der drei Varianten (warum müssen Kommentare so kurz sein? (; ).

Comment: Danke! Hab das fehlende Beispiel dazugegeben. Ich hatte das Gefühl, den Unterschied zwischen Eins und Drei verstanden zu haben, aber mittlerweile bin ich mir nicht mehr sicher. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ich denke, wenn Deutsch als eine Sprache verwendet wird, verwenden wir 'auf', dagegen aber 'in', wenn es als ein Fach verwendet wird.