# "Auf [eine Sprache]" - Etymologie

Tags: preposition

Warum verwendet man im Deutschen die Präposition "auf" im Zusammenhang mit Sprachen? Warum sagt man also **auf Deutsch**, **auf Englisch**, **auf Latein** etc?
In anderen Konstruktionen verwendet man ja auch "in"

> Ich bin fit in Englisch.

Gibt es einen etymologischen Grund für "auf"?

Und nochmal zur Sicherheit:

Ich will nicht wissen, wann man was benutzen kann. Das weiß ich selbst. Die "ähnliche Frage" hilft mir nicht.

Edit: Ich habe das Beispiel geändert. Danke @harper für den Vorschlag.

Comment: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1748/wann-kann-man-in-deutsch-und-wann-auf-deutsch-verwenden

Comment: *Ich bin fließend in Englisch.* klingt aber auch komisch. Ich würde sagen: *Ich spreche Englisch fließend.*

Comment: @chaero Ja, hört sich nach Denglisch an - *I am fluent in English*, wörtlich übersetzt.

Comment: Im Gegensatz zu Deutsch und Englisch wird für Latein deutlich häufiger „in“ als „auf“ verwendet. Siehe http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/ mit den Suchbegriffen „Latein“, „Deutsch“ und „Englisch“ im Abschnitt Signifikante linke Nachbarn.

Answer (score 3):

Bei Notker von St. Gallen findet sich die Ausdrucksweise ahd. "in diutiscûn". (J. Grimm - Deutsche Grammatik, Bd.4, S.891). Evtl. geht der Gebrauch der Präposition "auf" in diese Zeit zurück. Als das Althochdeutsche als Schriftsprache zunehmend an Bedeutung gewann, wurde immer mehr lateinische Literatur übertragen (lat. in ...). Bei der Übersetzung könnte es zu einer Konkurrenz zwischen den Präpositionen gekommen sein, dadurch, dass die Schreiblandschaft im deutschen Sprachgebiet noch stark dialektal zergliedert war.