# Is there a two-step German vocabulary test that estimates how many words you know?

Tags: vocabulary, online-resource

#### In English

Is there an online resource where you mark checkboxes with words that you definitely know (at least one meaning) and it estimates how much words do you know?

- English - http://testyourvocab.com/
- Russian - http://www.myvocab.info/
- German - ?

---

#### In Deutsch:

Gibt es Onlineseiten, wo ich Kontrollkästchen mit mir bekannten Wörter abhake, sodass daraus mein deutscher Wortschatz abgeschätzt werden kann?
Normalerweise gibt es zwei Schritte: Je mehr Wörter man auf der ersten Seite markiert hat, desto schwerer sind die Wörter auf der zweiten Seite. Am Ende bekommt man eine Zahl, die aussagt, wie viele Wörter man in etwa kennt. Oben sind Beispiele für englische und russische Wortschatztests verlinkt.

Comment: Shall I also try translating the question into German?

Comment: No need to translate. Questions are welcome in both English and German. If you like to practice your German, it's a good idea to ask in German, though. ;)

Comment: The English test is really fun, I learned a lot of new words. :-) The blog about their results is also really interesting. I don't know about something similar for German, but maybe some universities would be interested in making a similar test for reasearch purposes?

Comment: @dirkt, Note that if you learn specifically the words that are in this test (it's always the same set, as far as I remember), further test results would be inadequate.

Comment: @Vi.: I don't plan to take the test a second time. :-)

Comment: [Hier](http://www.itt-leipzig.de/static/deutschrez.html) gibt es einen rezeptiven Wortschatztest, der beantwortet ob man die häufigsten 1000/2000/3000/4000/5000 Wörter in Deutsch kennt.

Comment: @Iris, Es sagte `29/30, 23/30, 16/30, X, X`. Ist das schlecht (für B1.1)?

Comment: Auf der Seite steht eine Erklärung,  was die Punkte bedeuten. Mehr weiß ich auch nicht.

Comment: @Em1 My edit is rejected by the system as too minor, but it's "auf Deutsch" not "in Deutsch".

Comment: @Roland I can't find your edit in the history. Did I reject your edit? — Anyway, I don't think that "In Deutsch" is really wrong, see also [this question](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/1748/1224). But other than that it is indeed to minor, even if "in" were totally wrong.

Comment: The Russian test is a joke. I know about 500 words but the test gave me a score of 27000. It hammers you with words that are obviously Latin cognates like "instryument". Yes, there are probably 27000 words of that type in Russian, but so what?

Comment: A side note: I think it should be "...how **many** words you know". Roughly: "much" refers to uncountable things (much water, much air...), and "many" refers to countable things (many words, many apples...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is one now: https://wortschatz.tk. Full disclosure: I am this test's developer.

It is a two-page test, but the choices on the second page are not adaptive. I was pondering that pretty long but ended up not trusting the statistics of that method because of the underlying assumptions about the distribution of vocabulary.

There is a good deal of background info on the page in German, with a very detailed text in English coming soon.

Comment: Na toll, ich kenne nur 38000 Wörter.

Comment: Ich komm auf 46000 Wörter, aber ich habe definitiv dabei wieder paar neue Wörter gelernt ;) Schöner Test!

Comment: 6800! Wusste aber nicht, dass ich so viele kannte. Ich habe gedacht, dass es 3000 oder so wäre.

Comment: Es zeigte mir 11000, obwohl ich kenne vielleicht viel weniger Wörter. Warum gibt es so viel medizinische Wörter an der zweiten Seite?

Comment: Like the Russian test, this test is heavy on the Latin cognates which artificially inflate your word count. I'm really only interested in how many German words I know that aren't identical to the English and French equivalents.

Comment: @Vi. Dass Du diesen Eindruck hast, liegt warscheinlich an der Quelle, die ich benutzt habe, nämlich an OpenThesaurus. (Ich beschreibe in den Texten, die Du unter Hintergrund lesen kasst, wie ich den Test entwickelt habe.)

Comment: @MartyGreen What you're asking for is a very difficult thing. All of the words in the test are German words; they have been attested with a well-known frequency in written corpora of German texts. Also, the line between a loan word and a "German" word is unclear: just think about Grenze, which is from Slavic. I did manually review the word list and strived to avoid cognates with a Latin origin that are common international or English words.

Comment: @MartyGreen > I believe the ones that did remain are also very rare words in other languages, which means that a native speaker with a more narrow vocabulary in either German or a foreign language would be equally unlikely to know them. So marking them will no doubt inflate your result, but I doubt that the effect is artificial.

Comment: In my German word list, there are now 24405 German words. Plus I know an unknown number of words that are similar in many languages (e.g. Philatelie = philately). However, according to the test result, I know about 18500 German words.

Answer (score 1):

[Hier](http://www.itt-leipzig.de/static/deutschrez.html) gibt es einen rezeptiven Wortschatztest, der beantwortet, ob man die häufigsten 1000/2000/3000/4000/5000 Wörter in Deutsch kennt.

Es gibt dabei jeweils einen Frageblock zu jeder Wortschatzmenge. Pro Frageblock kann man 30 Punkte erreichen. Bei einem Punktestand zwischen 27 und 30 Punkte hat man den Frageblock bestanden, d.h. man kennt die entsprechende Wortschatzmenge (siehe [*Was bedeutet mein Ergebnis* unter dem Fragenblock](http://www.itt-leipzig.de/static/deutschrez.html))

Comment: Den Test gibt es auch in einer produktiven Form. Siehe http://www.itt-leipzig.de/static/startseite.html

Answer (score 0):

This website allows you to test your reading comprehension, listening comprehension, and vocabulary:

http://www.sprachtest.de/einstufungstest-deutsch

It doesn't give you a number, but estimates your level in the common European framework of reference for foreign languages (A1 - C1; it cannot distinguish between C1 & C2 at the top level, I think).

Comment: **Warning**: the test requires participants to disclose personal information (especially an email adress) before being able to view the test results.

Comment: Die Frage war nach einem Wortschatztest, keinem (allgemeinen) Sprachtest. Grammatik  z.B. spielt für Wortschatztests keine Rolle

Comment: Yes, it's not exactly what the OP requested, but similar enough that it might be of interest.

If you're concerned about disclosing personal information, getting a single-use disposable email address is fairly easy and cheap.