# Are there differences between "in [Language]", "im [Language]+en" and "auf [Language]", or can they be used interchangeably?

Tags: meaning

Essentially, I have three questions:

1. The name of the language is always capitalized with ***auf***, but when is the name of the language capitalized with ***in***? (i.e. *in deutsch* vs. *in Deutsch*)
2. Is *in Englisch* an anglicism when not referring to the (school) subject? If yes, does it therefore mean that it should be *i**m** Englisch**en*** when referring to the language?
3. Can the versions with ***im*** [Nomen]+**en** and ***auf*** be used interchangeably, or are there differences in their usage?

Regarding (1), [this thread on Leo](http://dict.leo.org/forum/viewGeneraldiscussion.php?idThread=483101) purportedly cites Rechtschreibduden from 1980:

> deutsch; [...] B. als Artangabe: deutsch (auf deutsche Art, in
>   deutscher Weise, von deutscher Abstammung, in deutschem Wortlaut); zu
>   deutsch, auf deutsch, auf gut deutsch, in deutsch (in deutschem Text,
>   Wortlaut; vgl. auch: in Deutsch)
> Deutsch das; (die deutsche
>   Sprache [...]) [...] er kann, lehrt, lernt, schreibt, spricht,
>   versteht [kein, nicht, gut, schlecht] Deutsch (vgl. aber: deutsch, B)
>   [...] am Ende des Artikels steht eine Zusammenfassung in Deutsch (in
>   der Sprache Deutsch); der Prospekt erscheint in Deutsch und in
>   Englisch (in den Sprachen Deutsch und Englisch; vgl. auch: in
>   deutsch); in heutigem Deutsch od. im heutigen Deutsch, vgl. auch
>   Deutsche, das und deutsch.

Is writing *deutsch* (in lowercase) still correct, is this citation outdated, or are both correct but with different usages? The same thread purportedly cites Duden 9 (2007) regarding the question of capitalization, which seems to contradict the previous entry:

> Nach den Präpositionen **auf**, **in**, und **zu** schreibt man ***Deutsch*** groß:
> *Am Ende des Artikels steht eine Zusammenfassung auf / in Deutsch.
> Der Prospekt erscheint auf / in Deutsch und Englisch.
> Ihre Gedichte schreibt sie auf Deutsch, ihre Prosatexte auf Englisch.*

Regarding (2) I often hear that *in Englisch* is incorrect German and an anglicism when referring to something that is written in a given language. The [entry for English at Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Englisch) seems to confirm this:

> 2. englische [und nordamerikanische] Sprache und Literatur als Unterrichts-, Lehrfach
>    Beispiel: *in Englisch eine Zwei haben*

Regarding (3), if I'm reading the Duden 2009 citation above correctly, there seems to be a deliberate attempt to provide an example (the last on the list) where it would be incorrect to use *in Deutsch*. However, I can't deduce just from that example the usage rule for **auf**.

Now, in the same thread, the other usage appears, namely *im Deutschen*:

> Wenn allerdings die Sprache gemeint ist, heißt es natürlich "auf
>   Englisch", das andere [in Englisch] ist ein böserböser Anglizismus. (Vermutlich aber
>   einer, der sich noch durchsetzen wird **im Deutschen**... ist schon sehr
>   weit verbreitet!)

Again, I can't parse just from the example what the usage rule is.

I have a vague memory that *im Englischen* stands for *in der englischen Sprache*, but that can of course be a faulty memory and therefore completely wrong (do let me know if that's the case, please).

From a cursory search in Google, *im Englischen* seems to indicate that it is used for grammatical features of the language, e.g. *Apostroph im Englischen*, *Satzbau im Englischen*, *Passiv im Englischen*, etc.

There are also plenty of examples for *in Englisch* when not referring to the subject: *Kurse in Englisch für das Wintersemester*, *International Management (BSc) in Englisch* (both from university websites), *[Book title] jetzt auch in Englisch!* (from an editorial)

*Auf Englisch* appears more often associated with the language in which a particular form of communication takes place, e.g. *auf Englisch schreiben*, *Tipps für Telefonate auf Englisch*, *Technische Dokumentation auf Englisch*

Thanks in advance for any help clearing this up!

Comment: Note that the spelling of _„auf deutsch“_ was changed to _„auf Deutsch“_ during the orthography reform of 1996.

Comment: [Closely related](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1748/wann-kann-man-in-deutsch-und-wann-auf-deutsch-verwenden)

Comment: @c.p. you're right, they're very closely related if not duplicates. I didn't find that question when googling or searching the site, though (probably because I searched in English)

Comment: Question 3 is the interesting part, I guess. Question 2 might be a duplicate, and Question 1 is only about orthography, which is boring :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether you capitalize a language name or not depends on whether you use it as an adjective or as a nominalized adjective or noun.

Some examples from Duden 1 (2004):

> **I. Kleinschreibung**
>
> - der Redner hat **deutsch** (nicht **englisch**) gesprochen
> - am Nebentisch saß ein […] **deutsch** sprechendes Ehepaar
> - der Brief ist **deutsch** (in deutscher Sprache od. in deutscher Schreibschrift) geschrieben
>
> **II. Großschreibung**
>
> - etw. auf **Deutsch** sagen
> - eine Zusammenfassung auf **Deutsch**
> - der Brief ist in **Deutsch** abgefasst
> - das heißt auf/zu **Deutsch**

Although the cited edition seems dated, you can verify on the [Duden website](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/deutsch) that the examples or rules haven't changed.

As you can already see, whether the language is an adjective or a noun is determined by whether you have a preposition in front of it.

Which preposition to use depends mostly on context and preference. The inflective noun form *das Deutsche* always goes with *in* + dative:

> - **im Deutschen** werden Substantive großgeschrieben

The nominalized adjective **Deutsch** (referring to the German language) can go with either *in* or *auf* as modal prepositions which are both interchangeable. I cannot find any evidence that *in* is an anglicism except for personal beliefs of Internet language advocates. In fact, *in* occurs in examples throughout all Duden editions without any annotation to foreign origin. Let me also add that language and color terms are very closely related and share mostly the same grammatical rules (comp. Duden 4, rule 474). For nominalized color adjectives, *in* is very common and nobody would argue that **in Blau** was an anglicism (e.g. in the sentence „Er hat die Möbel *blau/in Blau* gestrichen“ compared to „Er hat das Buch *deutsch/in Deutsch* verfasst“).

So according to the rules both *in* and *auf* are correct. There are, however, some slight differences in sound and flow. Let me warn you that the following statements are highly subjective and some people may or will disagree.

When referring to spoken language I tend to prefer *auf*:

> - **auf Deutsch** gesagt
> - sie hat die Rede **auf Deutsch** gehalten
> - der Film ist **auf Englisch**

When referring to written language I slightly prefer *in* when we're talking about existence or availability:

> - die Ausgabe gibt es **in Deutsch und Englisch**
> - wir haben das Buch auch **in Englisch**

Again, these are no rules, just very nit-picky and subjective preferences. In all these examples both *in* and *auf* are correct and sound perfectly fine to me. The only exception is the very first one „*auf Deutsch* gesagt“ where I would always prefer *auf*, although I can't find any rule that would forbid *in*.

Comment: Quote:  "The inflective noun form das Deutsche **always** goes with in + dative:" Are you sure about this ? For example: Übersetzung vom Englischen ins Deutsche.  Seconly, could you please explain, why we can not say: "Übersetzung vom Englisch ins Deutsch", using nouns, Englisch und Deutsch. Thanks

Comment: "Vom Englischen ins Deutsche" is meant in the sense "from...into". I am not entirely sure if that's an exception to the rule or just the same rule as in appears here as well, although used as a direction ("ins" is just the contracted form for "in das" meaning into). "Vom Englisch ins Deutsch" is just wrong, because the base form is "das Deutsche", with -e at the end, which is inflected to -en and -e in the third and fourth form.