# »In der Muttersprache sprechen«, aber »auf Deutsch«?

Tags: preposition, phrase

> Ich möchte gerne mit einem Deutschen [in/auf] seiner Muttersprache sprechen.

I know that the answer is *in.* But I don’t really understand why. For example:

> Ich würde lieber auf Deutsch sprechen als auf English.

Here we use *auf.* So, must I use *auf* with names of languages?

Comment: Related: [Wann kann man “in Deutsch” und wann “auf Deutsch” verwenden?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/1748/9551)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, I think so.

If you use *Sprache*, then you also use *in*. If you use only the name of the language, then it’s *auf*.

Take for example:

> Ich schreibe auf Deutsch.

but when you bring in the word *Sprache*, it becomes

> Ich schreibe in meiner Muttersprache.

even like this

> Ich schreibe in deutscher Sprache.

You will probably not find this in the Duden or similar resources, though. It's more of a gut choice, how the prepositions feel to me.