# German Pangrams

Tags: translation, german-to-english

Do you know any German pangrams that use special characters like `ö`, `ä` etc?

If possible, with their english translation and transliteration in ASCII characters.

Answer (score 8):

- Zwölf Boxkämpfer jagen Viktor quer über den großen Sylter Deich

More can be found at http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangramm#Liste_deutscher_Pangramme

Comment: So many thanx for the link, I finally understand the origin of the mythic sentence: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".

Answer (score 7):

There is a perfect (each letter appears exactly once) pangram in German. It uses old-style spelling (Paß instead of Pass) though:

> »Fix, Schwyz!«, quäkt Jürgen blöd vom Paß.

Comment: It's the only one? Is there anything using only common nouns and no Denglish? ;)

Comment: @Łukasz웃Lツ As far as I am concerned, that's the only one.