# Perfect pangram using only common words?

Tags: wordplay

Is there any German perfect pangram using only common words?

The only one that I've found, was in another question here – [German Pangrams](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5015/german-pangrams/5018#5018):

> »Fix, Schwyz!«, quäkt Jürgen blöd vom Paß.

But it is using 2 non-common words (a first name (Jürgen) and a nationality name in regional variant (Schwyz)).

There are a lot of them in Polish and quite a few in English (although using the words, I suppose, are not known to regular native speaker). It would be surprising, if there were none in German.

**--edit--**
Actually, the after the discussion on [English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167709/a-perfect-honest-pangram-that-is-understandable-for-a-regular-native-user) I've got an idea that in the languages like German creating a perfect pangram may be much more difficult because the consonant clusters aren't as common and as different as in Polish, so it's harder to use all consonants without running out of vowels.

Comment: This one is not correct any more: the last word should be _Pass_.

Comment: »Schwyz« is not a regional variant of the nationality name »Schweiz«, but the name of one of the three founding cantons of Switzerland (even though, historically, »Schweiz« is derived from »Schwyz«).

Comment: While it is true that Umlaute are not in themselves considered Letters by a lot of Germans for pourposes of pangram's, it is quite irrelevant since you want all "letter" characters in a font to appear. So within a pangram, they should still appear.

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't. There's the classic

> Zwölf Boxkämpfer jagen Viktor quer über den großen Sylter Deich

and since neither the umlauts (ä,ö,ü) nor ß are technically considered letters proper of the German alphabet, I could also offer

> Franz jagt im komplett verwahrlosten Taxi quer durch Bayern

All of those repeat certain letters, though. [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangramm#Deutsch) has lots more, including a link to [this site](http://faql.de/sonstiges.html#pangramme).

Comment: I've seen the list on wikipedia, but it was, anyway, quite hard for me to believe, that no German poet have made a challenge like that and succeeded. Why? They were not trying, or something in letter distribution in German makes that task significantly harder?

Comment: The latter. There are practically no words without a vowel; German doesn't have consonant clusters like some other languages.

Comment: The perfect Polish pangram "Mężny bądź, ..." doesn't have vowel-free words, and its consonant clusters are even shorter than the "schw" in "Fix Schwyz ...", so I don't think that this is the main reason. One advantage of Polish is that "q", "v", "x" are considered as non-native letters, so they are not required to occur in a pangram. In German, "q", "x", y" are rare, but still considered as standard letters. Including them in a pangram is difficult.

Comment: »technically considered« does not work very well here. **Technically,** *ä, ö, ü* and *ß* are letters of the German alphabet, at least for any useful definition of alphabet (also, if you want something official, it’s in the spelling rules). Only for historical reasons, they are **considered** not to be letters by some. Anyway, what is a letter and what isn’t only matters in crossword puzzles and similar and to language learners (and children), for which everything but a 30-letter German alphabet is only confusing.

Comment: @Łukasz웃Lツ Your conjecture that the letter distribution in German makes it difficult is probably correct. German has a rather extreme letter distribution: The two most frequent letters in German, i.e. "e" and "n", make up 17% and 10% of an average German text, so it's pretty hard to avoid the second or third "e" and the second "n" within 30 characters. In Polish, the most frequent letters are "a" (12%), "i" (9%), "e" (8%), and "o" (7%), so the distribution of vowels is a lot more balanced.

Comment: No, umlaute are not part of the alphabet, as far as I'm concerned, otherwise we'd refer to them as letters, they way, say, the Danish do with ø and å.